# In Go, how to check that an interface implements all of a struct's exported methods?

Tags: go, reflection, interface, go-interface, reflect

I'm working on a Go library in which I've used the `interfacer` tool (https://github.com/rjeczalik/interfaces) to create an interface from a struct, and subsequently ran `moq` (https://github.com/matryer/moq) to generate a mock object for that interface. Now I would like to write a unit test that fails if someone adds an exported method to the struct without updating the interface and the mocks.

At a high level, it seems to me that I could get the `reflect.Value` of both the interface and the struct and call `NumMethod()` on each and then check that the numbers are equal. I'm struggling to implement this idea, however.

For example, if I try this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type PersonInterface interface {
    GetName() string
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func (person *Person) GetName() string {
    return person.Name
}

func main() {
    person := Person{}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(&person)
    fmt.Println(v.NumMethod())

    var personInterface PersonInterface
    w := reflect.ValueOf(personInterface)
    fmt.Println(w.NumMethod())
}
```

I'm able to call get the number of methods of the `person`, but not of the `personInterface`, as this panics with the error message

> reflect: call of reflect.Value.NumMethod on zero Value

Here is the full error:

```
> go run assert_struct.go
1
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.NumMethod on zero Value

goroutine 1 [running]:
reflect.Value.NumMethod(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/reflect/value.go:1262 +0xc1
main.main()
    /Users/kurt/Documents/Scratch/assert_struct.go:27 +0x1a5
exit status 2
```

How could I get the number of methods implemented by an `interface`, and more generally, how would I go about checking that an interface implements all exported methods of a struct?

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/a5qyB6fFi2l

Answer (score 1):

To convert `mkopriva`'s Go Playground comment to an answer, `reflect.ValueOf()` needs to be called on a pointer to the interface (`PersonInterface`) and then `Elem()` needs to be called on that:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type PersonInterface interface {
    GetName() string
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func (person *Person) GetName() string {
    return person.Name
}

func main() {
    person := Person{}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(&person)
    fmt.Println(v.NumMethod())

    var personInterface PersonInterface
    w := reflect.ValueOf(&personInterface)
    fmt.Println(w.Elem().NumMethod())
}
```

This is actually similar to the procedure to make a value settable as described in the 'Three Laws of Reflection' blog (https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection).